# Netbeans API won't access JAVA on Mac OSX

Tags: java, macos, netbeans

My windows machine is at the tech support, meanwhile my substitute laptop is a macbook. I am not familiar with the system and I am having trouble to make Netbeans run java code.

If i try to import .zip java projects, it says "No Netbeans projects added".

When i look if i have a JDK in Tools --> java platforms I have default 1.8jdk
with a lot of files listed, so i do not think the JDK is the problem?

I downloaded netbeans with a JDK in a bundle as well.

I am unable to run any java code, the buttons are simply just grey instead of colored and if i try to use keyboard commands to make the laptop execute the code it comes with a error sound.

I read something about it could be ant variables, but not much information was given. But when i go tools --> ant variables it shows nothing.

When i try to create new files it only gives me two options: XML and other. In the other category there is; SQL, HTML and CSS. So no option for creating java files either.

Answers to comments:

I just trying deleting it at reinstalling from this domain http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/jdk-netbeans-jsp-142931.html

I cannot show you the command line, since i do not know the commands in Terminal. But in the JDK it says: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_141.jdk/Contents/Home

I cannot run ANY java code, since I cannot create java files. If i try to run a simple program in an empty file I cannot run it.

Comment: If by "the buttons are simply just grey" you mean NetBeans itself, then there's something wrong with your installation.  Try writing a simple "hello world" program, see if that will run.  If not, it's NetBeans or the JDK you have.

Comment: Based on your edit, it sounds like you don't have the JDK installed properly.  Open a command line window and show us the results of `java -version`.

Comment: I have answered your comments in an edit markspace